# Open browser link in Java

Tags: java, browser, process

So I've recently wrote code:

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
    Process p = null; 
    try 
    {
        p = r.exec("firefox"); 
        p.waitFor(); 
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error executing app");
    }
```

And I was wondering if there is a way to for example force the browser not just to open but execute certain commands or just open a link. How do I do that?

Comment: The `firefox` command can take a command line argument indicating the URL to go to. I'm not sure what "execute certain commands" means, but if you're looking to perform *actions* on a webpage, you want a web driver like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumframework.com/) (Selenium was originally written in Python, but based on the website it looks like they have a Java version)

Comment: Do you want to open the browser from executable or default browser?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open the default browser with an URL provided you can use this function. `java.awt.Desktop` is suitable for windows and `xdg-open` opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application in linux environment. If a URL is provided the URL will be opened in the default web browser.

```
    public void openDefaultBrowser(URI uri) throws BrowserException {
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported() && Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
            // windows
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            try {
                desktop.browse(uri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new BrowserException(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        } else {
            // linux / mac
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
                runtime.exec("xdg-open " + uri.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new BrowserException(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```